# TIMESTAMP literals in FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF don't default to UTC

Tags: google-bigquery, timezone, temporal-tables

[Google BigQuery documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#timestamp_literals)...

> A timestamp literal can include a numerical suffix to indicate the
> time zone:
>
> `TIMESTAMP '2014-09-27 12:30:00.45-08'`
>
> If this suffix is absent, the default time zone, UTC, is used.

This is also what I observe **except** in context of the `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` clause.

E.g. if I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM doesnt.matter FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP'2020-12-16 17:59:14.445596'
```

I get the following error message:

> 'FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF' expression for table 'doesntmatter' evaluates
> to a TIMESTAMP value in the future: 2020-12-17 01:59:14.445596 UTC.

The interesting part is the timestamp in the error message: It says UTC but is clearly different from the one in my query (which should be interpreted as UTC according to the docs above).

In fact I get the very same error message if I add a "-08" as a timezone to the timestamp literal. It seems that this 8 hour offset isn't affected by the dataset location (I get the same error whether I use US or EU).

If I add an explicit UTC timezone to the timestamp, the error message makes sense:

```
SELECT * FROM doesnt.matter FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP'2020-12-16 17:59:14.445596 UTC'
```

> Not found: Dataset [...]:doesnt was not found in location US

(Neither dataset nor table existed at any time).

Am I doing something wrong (am I missing something in the docs) or is this a BigQuery issue?

---

**Workaround**

In the [ticket, Google also presents this workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175803957#comment3):

```
SET @@time_zone = 'UTC';
```

---

For clarity, the same problem persists when actually creating a table (based on the [example given in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#for_system_time_as_of)):

```
-- Create table books.
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.books AS
SELECT 'Hamlet' title, 'William Shakespeare' author;

-- Get current timestamp before table replacement.
SELECT current_timestamp;

-- Replace table with different schema(title and release_date).
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.books AS
SELECT 'Hamlet' title, DATE '1603-01-01' release_date;

-- Manually copy and paste the timestamp from line the SELECT current_timestamp query without timezone:
SELECT * FROM doesnt.matter FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP'<<paste here>>';
```

Comment: Feels like a bug. Could you create a ticket on BigQuery from https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers?

Comment: @YunZhang Done: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/175803957